# Detect angular template if/else change

Tags: angular, ng-template, angular-changedetection

I have a template that uses Angulars conditional template logic to display dynamic content. The value of the condition changes based on the response from an asynchronous function. After the function returns a value I would like to append a new element. The issue is that when I do this the new element is appended before the template changes, effectively removing the appended element.

Take a look at this stackblitz for a live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aty1zz

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  private hasAsyncResponded;
  private p: HTMLParagraphElement;

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.hasAsyncResponded = await this.getAsyncThing();
    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.textContent = 'foo bar baz';
    document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')[0].appendChild(this.p);
    // debugger;
  }

  get shouldShowTemplateTwo(): boolean {
    return this.hasAsyncResponded ? true : false;
  }

  async getAsyncThing(): Promise<boolean> {
    const promise: Promise<boolean> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true);
      }, 3000);
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="shouldShowTemplateTwo; then templateTwo else templateOne"></ng-container>
<ng-template #templateOne>
  <div class="my-div">
    <h1>Template 1</h1>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #templateTwo>
  <div class="my-div">  
    <h1>Template 2</h1>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

On line 9 of app.component.ts I define a variable called `hasAsyncResponded` which is falsy (undefined) by default.

On line 13 I await the response from an async function and store it as the value of `hasAsyncResponded`.

On line 20 I create a getter that is used by the template to conditionally show the desired `ng-template` (app.component.html: line 1).

After the promise resolves the value of `hasAsyncResponded` is set to true which switches the `ng-template`. Also after the promise resolves we get to line 16 of app.component.ts which appends a new paragraph to the template.

Since the promise has resolved and the value of `hasAsyncResponded` has been updated prior to the new paragraph being appended I would expect the new paragraph to be appended to the updated template (`#templateTwo`). However the paragraph gets appended to the former template (`#templateOne`). You can see this if you uncomment the debugger on line 17 of app.component.ts. When the debugger pauses code execution `#templateOne` is visible with the appended paragraph, after resuming code execution `#templateTwo` is displayed.

How do I get the paragraph appended to the correct template? I thought that maybe I just needed to detect changes before appending the new paragraph but that doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding that I was over complicating the issue.

I created a new property `shouldShowTemplateTwo` that defaults to false and is set to true when the awaited promise resolves.

Answer (score 0):

That is what the async pipe is for, assign the promise to a property on the component and use the async pipe in the template.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="yourPromise | async; then templateTwo else templateOne">
```

No need to subscribe to the promise in the TypeScript